# Checking inequalities: How can $x>0,y>0$ yet $x+y$ indeterminate?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, inequalities

I have the following:

```
$Assumptions = {0 < Ijm1 < Ij < Ijp1 < 1, bpjm1 < 0, bpj < 0, 
bpjp1 < 0, Ijm1 \[Element] Reals, Ij \[Element] Reals, 
Ijp1 \[Element] Reals, bpjm1 \[Element] Reals, bjp \[Element] Reals,
bpjp1 \[Element] Reals};

x = (1 - bpjp1 Ijp1 + bpjp1 Ijp1^2) ;
y = bpj (Ij - Ijm1) (-1 + Ij (1 + bpjp1 (-1 + Ijp1)) - 
bpjp1 (-1 + Ijp1) Ijp1);
```

When checking inequalities I get

```
In[243]:= Simplify[x > 0]
Out[243]= True

In[244]:= Simplify[y > 0]
Out[244]= True
```

but

```
In[245]:= Simplify[x + y > 0]  
Out[245]= 
1 + bpjp1 (-1 + Ijp1) Ijp1 + 
bpj (Ij - Ijm1) (-1 + Ij (1 + bpjp1 (-1 + Ijp1)) - 
bpjp1 (-1 + Ijp1) Ijp1) > 0
```

Why?

Comment: Can you tell us your precise version of Mathematica and try again after restarting the kernel (`Quit`)?  I get [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jOts8.png).

Comment: Aside from this: Simplify is not guaranteed to be able to perform the simplification.  It uses heuristics to try to arrive to a simpler result.  It may not be able to do it.  If `Simplify[expr > 0]` returns as `expr > 0`, it does not mean that `expr` is not always positive.  Usually, when Mathematica returns your input as-is, it means "I don't know".

Comment: Mathematica version: 10.0.1.0, Student Edition, Linux x86. Restarting the kernel did not help. In my original post I had a wrong definition of `y` to which your computation refers, sorry about that.

Comment: It won't fix this, but you *should* upgrade to at least 10.0.2, which fixed many bugs in 10.0.1.

Answer (score 11):

The assumptions mechanism used by Simplify has a bound on the number of variables in a system of nonlinear inequalities. If the number of variables exceeds the bound, the assumption mechanism does not attempt to decide whether the system has solutions. (Simplify proves that an inequality follows from the assumptions by showing that assumptions && Not[inequality] has no solutions.) The default value of the bound is 4, but it can be changed using a system option.

```
SetSystemOptions["SimplificationOptions"->{"AssumptionsMaxNonlinearVariables"->5}];

Simplify[x + y > 0]
True
```

Comment: Is that documented (other than here)? If so, where? If not, why not?

Comment: Thanks! This works, but I noticed that the order in which one sets the system options and evaluates `Simplify[x+y>0]` matters. If I first evaluate `Simplify[x+y>0]`, get the indeterminate result, then set the system options and try `Simplify[x+y>0]` again, I get `x+z>0`. If instead I set the system options before calling `Simplify[x+y>0]` for the first time, I get `True`.

Comment: That would be a caching effect. Many internal uses of caching do not record the state of system options. `ClearSystemCache[]` and variants thereof will flush the earlier computed result(s) so you can redo the computation after altering the system option.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer, but here's some analysis of the issue which didn't fit in a comment.

First, let us rewrite your assumptions in a slightly different form:

```
asmp = And @@ {0 < Ijm1 < Ij < Ijp1 < 1, bpjm1 < 0, bpj < 0, 
    bpjp1 < 0, Ijm1 ∈ Reals, Ij ∈ Reals, 
    Ijp1 ∈ Reals, bpjm1 ∈ Reals, 
    bjp ∈ Reals, bpjp1 ∈ Reals};
```

Now let's play with [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html):

```
Reduce[Implies[asmp, x > 0], Reals]
(* True *)

Reduce[Implies[asmp, y > 0], Reals]
(* True *)
```

All good so far.  But what about this?

```
res = Reduce[Implies[asmp, x + y > 0], Reals]
(* Ij < 
  1 || (Ij == 
    1 && (Ijm1 <= 
      0 || (0 < Ijm1 < 1 && (Ijp1 < 1 || Ijp1 == 1 || Ijp1 > 1)) || 
     Ijm1 >= 1)) || Ij > 1 *)
```

What is strange about this result is that:

```
Reduce[Implies[asmp, res], Reals]
(* True *)
```

And also that

```
Reduce[Implies[Reduce[asmp], x + y > 0], Reals]
(* True *)
```

Also that it contains things like `Ijp1 < 1 || Ijp1 == 1 || Ijp1 > 1`, which are obviously `True` and that it contains `Ijm1 <= 0` and `Ij > 1`, which contradict `asmp` so should be dropped.

Somehow `Reduce` doesn't seem to finish its job.