# Why does my inequality require "AssumptionsMaxNonlinearVariables" -> 14?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, inequalities

I have the following code for simplifying an inequality:

```
glbcond =
  {0 < d1 < 1, d1 ∈ Reals, 0 < d2 < 1, d2 ∈ Reals, 
   0 < d3 < 1, d3 ∈ Reals, 0 < e1 < 1, e1 ∈ Reals, 
   0 < e2 < 1, e2 ∈ Reals, 0 < e3 < 1, e3 ∈ Reals, 
   0 < Hd < 1, Hd ∈ Reals, 0 < Hu < 1, Hu ∈ Reals, 
   0 < L1 < 1, L1 ∈ Reals, 0 < L2 < 1, L2 ∈ Reals, 
   0 < L3 < 1, L3 ∈ Reals, 0 < Q1 < 1, Q1 ∈ Reals, 
   0 < Q2 < 1, Q2 ∈ Reals, 0 < Q3 < 1, Q3 ∈ Reals, 
   0 < u1 < 1, u1 ∈ Reals, 0 < u2 < 1, u2 ∈ Reals, 
   0 < u3 < 1, u3 ∈ Reals};

z2cond = 
  Hd < Hu < L1 < L2 < L3 < Q1 < Q2 < Q3 < u1 < u2 < u3 < d1 < d2 < d3;

Simplify[Abs @ (Q1 u1)/(d2 Q3) < 1, (And @@ glbcond) && z2cond]
```

> `Q1 u1 < d2 Q3`

However, if I turn up the `SystemOptions` as suggested by this related post [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/118492/checking-inequalities-how-can-x0-y0-yet-xy-indeterminate/118515#118515) as

```
SetSystemOptions[
  "SimplificationOptions" -> "AssumptionsMaxNonlinearVariables" -> 14]
```

I get

```
Simplify[Abs[(Q1 u1)/(d2 Q3)] < 1, glbcond && z2cond]
```

> `True`

So my question is, how exactly are the numbers of non-linear variables calculated? As far as I can see from my example, all the inequalities inside the argument for assumption are linear. Or does the calculation of number of non-linear variables involve both of the two arguments sitting inside `Simplify`?

This my first post on Mathematica.SE. I hope my post meets the site's posting conventions :)

Comment: The way I see it is that your rational/polynomial inequality is nonlinear and the 4 variables in it are related to each of the variables in `z2cond`. Thus `{Abs[(Q1 u1)/(d2 Q3)] < 1, z2cond}` form a nonlinear ***system***, which has 14 variables. (The whole with `glbcond` has 17 variables, but the `e1`, `e2`, `e3` components can be factored out as a direct product and treated as linear....But I don't know for sure that's how *Mathematica* approaches it.)

Comment: Hi! I was wondering the same thing, but my question comes from these lines of codes `In[43]:= SetSystemOptions["SimplificationOptions"->"AssumptionsMaxNonlinearVariables"->9];
ClearSystemCache[];
Simplify[Abs@((Hd Hu)/Q1)<1,glbcond&&z2cond]
Out[45]= True`, which now only requires `"AssumptionsMaxNonlinearVariables"->9`

Answer (score 2):

To simplify an inequality ineq to True using assumptions assum Simplify needs to prove that `assum && Not[ineq]` has no solutions. Hence non-linearity of both assum and ineq matter and all variables in assum and ineq are counted.

Comment: Hi Adam, thank you for the answer! I see that both arguments of Simplify are counted for their non-linear variables. But in this particular case, why does it require 14 non-linear variables, since the rational function of ineq can always be converted a polynomial inequality, with all inequalities inside assum being linear? It would be helpful if some details can be given on this as I have quite a lot of similar inequalities that need similar simplification. :)

Comment: Simplify counts variables in the system for which it needs to decide the existence of solutions, that is assum && Not[ineq]. If the system is nonlinear (in any of the variables) then the number of all variables cannot exceed the value of  "AssumptionsMaxNonlinearVariables".

Comment: So the non-linearity is introduced by the rational function `(Q1 u1)/(d2 Q3)` through substituting this into the inequalities in 14 variable expression of `z2cond`, as suggested by @Michael E2 in previous comments? If so, why is this particular codes requiring `"AssumptionsMaxNonlinearVariables"->9`:`In[43]:= SetSystemOptions["SimplificationOptions"->"AssumptionsMaxNonlinearVariables"->9];
ClearSystemCache[];
Simplify[Abs@((Hd Hu)/Q1)<1,glbcond&&z2cond]
Out[45]= True`

Comment: Simplify splits z2cond into two-argument inequalities and it has a heuristic that attempts to select a subset of assumptions sufficient for the given simplification. In this case it must be finding a subset of assumptions that involves 9 variables and is sufficient to prove that ineq is true.