# Why does Simplify work diferently for (a+b)/e versus (a+b+c)/e?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions

I am playing around with `Simplify` amd assumptions. I noticed that:

```
Simplify[x > (a + b)/e, x < (a + b)/e]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

But if I add more variables to the numerator, `Simplify` is not able to get `False`

```
Simplify[x > (a + b + c)/e, x < (a + b + c)/e]
```

> ```
> x > (a + b + c)/e
> ```

Why is there such a difference and how can I avoid the latter situation?

Comment: Note that `Reduce[{x > (a + b + c)/e, x < (a + b + c)/e}]` does return `False` as expected, so that might be a work-around.

Comment: `Simplify[x > (a + b + c)/e && x < (a + b + c)/e]`

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/118492/checking-inequalities-how-can-x0-y0-yet-xy-indeterminate

Answer (score 6):

You can set a higher value for the system sub-option `"AssumptionsMaxNonlinearVariables"` than its default value `4`:

```
"AssumptionsMaxNonlinearVariables" /. 
    "SimplificationOptions" /. 
       SystemOptions["SimplificationOptions"]
```

> ```
>  4
> ```

```
Simplify[x > (a + b + c)/e, x < (a + b + c)/e]
```

> ```
>  x > (a + b + c)/e
> ```

```
Simplify[x > (a + b + c + z)/e, x < (a + b + c + z)/e]
```

> ```
>  x > (a + b + c + z)/e
> ```

```
ClearSystemCache[]
SetSystemOptions["SimplificationOptions" -> {"AssumptionsMaxNonlinearVariables" -> 7}];

Simplify[x > (a + b + c)/e, x < (a + b + c)/e]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

```
Simplify[x > (a + b + c + z)/e, x < (a + b + c + z)/e]
```

> ```
> False
> ```